# Contribute to TestCafe repo for features/fixes

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I want to take a stab at contributing code to TestCafe for bugs/issues.

Can anyone of the contributers help me with setting up my machine? How do you get started? (apart from forking the repo) Are there any tools/extension that specifically help you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming trouble with actual code. You should ask TestCafe team instead. However, these are their [official guidelines for contributing](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: I don't see their team email address on their site, they redirect to StackOverflow for questions

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is a prerequisite and needs to be installed on your machine. You need to run `npm install` or `yarn` in the local copy of the repository after it is cloned. You can use `gulp build` to build the project without running tests. After the project is built, you can start TestCafe by executing `node bin/testcafe.js <TestCafe args>` in your terminal.

You can use any text editor of your choice. JetBrains Webstorm is an ultimate solution for a JS project like TestCafe, but it is paid and proprietary. Visual Studio Code is a good open-source and free alternative.

As for other questions, I suggest you refer to the [Code Contribution](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#code-contribution) section of our guide, which covers the majority of topics.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Do I pass a new JS file(with tests) as an argument? To see if it actually runs in a browser? Is there a Slack workspace or a Discord that I can join? where someone can help me on these minute things more?

Comment: Yes, you still need to specify complete CLI parameters for TestCafe including a test file. You can use the [examples/basic/test.js](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/examples/basic/test.js) file located in the repository. We do not use Slack and Discord, so you can continue using StackOverflow for any TestCafe-related questions, including development ones.